# MySQL slow query, joined table by points inside circle

Tags: mysql

Im trying to get this query working, unfortunately it's pretty slow. So i'm guessing there could be a better query for getting the result I'm looking for.

```
Select samples.X, samples.Y, samples.id, samples.Provnr, samples.costumer_id, avg(lerhalter.lerhalt) from samples
  left outer join lerhalter
on SQRT(POW(samples.X - lerhalter.x , 2) + POW(samples.Y - lerhalter.y, 2)) < 100
  where samples.customer_id = 900417
group by samples.provnr
```

I have the table samples, and i'd like to get all the customers samples, and then join the "lerhalt" table. There could be more than one row of each sample when i do the join, therefore id like to get the average value of column lerhalt.

I think i get the result that I'm after, but the query can take up to 10s, for a customer with only 100 samples. There's customers with 2000 samples. 
So i have to get a better query time.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Ask one question. When you have the answer to that, ask the other question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A small speed up would be to leave out the SQRT function. SQRT() is expensive in terms of computing time and you can simply adjust the right side of your comparison to 100x100 = 10.000:

```
Select samples.X, samples.Y, samples.id, samples.Provnr, samples.costumer_id, avg(lerhalter.lerhalt) from samples
  left outer join lerhalter
on (POW(samples.X - lerhalter.x , 2) + POW(samples.Y - lerhalter.y, 2)) < 10000
  where samples.customer_id = 900417
group by samples.provnr
```

Also, are you sure you need a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`? Could an `INNER JOIN` be used instead?

Next question: Are the X and Y coordinated integer values? If not, can they be converted to integers? Integer claucuations are a lot faster usually than floating point operations.

Finally, you clearly do a euclidean distance measure. Is that really needed? Can another distance measure do a sufficiently good job? Maybe city-block distance is good enough for your needs? This would further speed up things a lot.

Comment: Both table's coordinate columns are integers. 
SQRT did not make that much difference, but the join method tid, inner join was 3,6 s compared to 8 s. Ill think about using it..
The samples are the results of GPS logged soil samples, taken somewhere on a farmers field. They are scattered on a big area. I need to specify a value in meters for the search radius.
Got any other ideas?  Tried a query with a result of 1339 rows, took 86 seconds. 

When applied in real world it will not be used for results > 300.  But you know, you always want to speed things up.

Comment: You could maybe have two queries. First with a much rougher estimate of the distance, e.g. using city block distance measure and then on the result set apply the euclidean distance calculus. This should speed up things further but gets cumbersome since you need now two queries. Often speed improvements come at a price. Also, don't forget to up-vote  and possible accept the answer if it was helpful.